# Java soap calls to pass an .XML file to WebService

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

So I am new to the whole SOAP and server concept. Ive put together a basic JAX-RPC and JAX-WS. I overall want to pass an .XML file to a web service, receive a response, and write it into a directory. Where do i start, what should I use, and where can find a tutorial/information based on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially there are two approaches you can take when designing a web service. The top down approach and the bottom up approach. I will give you a brief explanation of both methods and their ups and downs. There will also be links to some tutorials.

**Top Down:**

In the top down approach you start by modelling a XSD which will contain your request and response messages and the data structures that those requests and responses will use. You then model the operations i.e. the request and response that flows between client and service and finally you put this together into a WSDL. This resulting WSDL is then imported into a IDE such as Netbeans or Eclipse and you then start coding the internals of the service.

For example lets say you have a product service. In this service you want to create a operation that will search for a particular product based on product code. Thus you want to query the product service for product objects. The service will be called `ProductService` and the operation will be called `GetProduct`.

To achieve this you need to model a product object which has two string properties called description and code. You will also need to model a `GetProductRequest` message and a `GetProductResponse` message.

This might take on the following structures:

[image: XSD Screen Shot]

The code for the XSD would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.wsexample.com/ProductService_V1/Product"
       elementFormDefault="qualified"
       targetNamespace="http://www.wsexample.com/ProductService_V1/Product"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:simpleType name="ProductCode_Type">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>This the product code type. It is based on the string data type it must be 8 characters long.
</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="8" />
        <xs:maxLength value="8" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="ProductDescription_Type">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>This is the base class for the product description field. This is a text field up to 255 characters long.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="255" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:complexType name="Product_Type">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>This is the product base class it is used to perform CRUD operations with on all of the product service operations.
</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ProductCode"
                    type="ProductCode_Type"
                    minOccurs="1"
                    maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="ProductDescription"
                    type="ProductDescription_Type"
                    minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="GetProductRequest_Type">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>This is the base class for the Get Product Request message. In the message you must pass one and only one product code which to search for.   </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Product"
                    type="Product_Type" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="GetProductResponse_Type">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>This is the get product response message and will contain the result of the results of calling the getproductdescription operation on the Product service.
It will contain a product code which was passed in the Get Product Request message and optionally return one description.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Product"
                    type="Product_Type" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="GetProductRequest"
            type="GetProductRequest_Type" />
<xs:element name="GetProductResponse"
            type="GetProductResponse_Type" />
</xs:schema>
```

You will now need to create a new WSDL to describe the service and use this XSD(I called it product.xsd) in this WSDL. As you can see we have modelled data structures to transport the product object and we have modeled the operations used in the service.

Our WSDL might look like this then:

[image: WSDL Picture]

This is the code for the WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <wsdl:definitions name="ProductService"
              targetNamespace="http://wsexample.com/ProductService"
              xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
              xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
              xmlns:tns="http://wsexample.com/ProductService"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
              xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
              xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
              xmlns:ProductData="http://www.wsexample.com/Product/ProductData">
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
               targetNamespace="http://wsexample.com/ProductService">
        <xs:import schemaLocation="Product.xsd"
                   namespace="http://www.wsexample.com/Product/ProductData" />
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="GetProduct">
    <wsdl:part name="in"
               element="ProductData:GetProductRequest" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetProductRs">
    <wsdl:part name="out"
               element="ProductData:GetProductResponse" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ProductEndPoint">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetProduct">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:GetProduct" />
        <wsdl:output message="tns:GetProductRs" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="ProductServiceBinding"
              type="tns:ProductEndPoint">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
                  style="document" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetProduct">
        <wsdl:input>
         <soap:body parts="in"
                       use="literal" />

        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body parts="out"
                       use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ProductEndpointService">
    <wsdl:port name="ProductServiceEndPointPort"
               binding="tns:ProductServiceBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://wsexample.com/ProductService" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

So after all that modeling the message that will flow between the client and server will look like this:

**Request:**

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:prod="http://www.wsexample.com/Product/ProductData">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
   <prod:GetProductRequest>
      <prod:Product>
         <prod:ProductCode>12345678</prod:ProductCode>

      </prod:Product>
   </prod:GetProductRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Response:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prod="http://www.wsexample.com/Product/ProductData">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
    <prod:GetProductResponse>
       <prod:Product>
          <prod:ProductCode>12345678</prod:ProductCode>
          <!--Optional:-->
          <prod:ProductDescription>A Basic product for kids to teach them how to count.    </prod:ProductDescription>
       </prod:Product>
    </prod:GetProductResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now you can use the WSDL and XSD to implement the web service using this [Netbeans tutorial and guide.](https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/nbfieldguide/Chapter9-WebServices.pdf). Its very simple really just start a new web project in netbeans then right click the project and add new file then just select the web service from WSDL file.

See the screen shot below:
[image]

**Top down summary:**

Top down requires you to do a lot of modelling and planning up front. However you are in complete control. This allows you to decide how the data is going to flow between client and server. It allows you to modify everything to your exact requirements. However it requires a lot of work before hand.

The biggest benefit from me is that I can design a WSDL and XSD that abstracts the data away from the providing systems into something more generic. This become important in integration projects.

**Bottom Up:**

The bottom up approach allows you to generate the artifacts I created above from java code. There is a [excellent tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html) here that will show you all the details. However Java allows you to add annotations to a class that then exposes the class and its method as a web service.

So by taking a class and adding annotations you turn that class into a web service. See the code below for a quick and dirty example:

```
@Webservice
public Class CalculatorWS
{

    @WebMethod
    public int add(@WebParam(name = "i") int i, @WebParam(name = "j") int j) {
        int k = i + j;
        return k;
    }
}
```

If you follow the tutorial you will probably go from code to fully working web service in a couple of minutes. Quick and easy.

**Bottom Up Summary:**

You have very little control over how your WSDL and XSD will look and behave. In some cases this approach will bind you tightly to the underlying model. It really depends on how you code it. So with bottom up approach you can have a prototype in minutes but the message flowing up and down might not be exactly what you had in mind.

***IMPORTANT TIP:***

Download a copy of SOAPUI it is really the best tool to use to test and even create mock services. If you are serious about using web services then get it now.

Hope this helps you down the rabbit hole.